# Sending data through an email instead of RESTful API

Tags: api, security, email, rest

I am trying to get some data from end users, no authentication is supported. 
What kind of attacks are not possible through an email, that are possible through a REST API? Is email somehow more secure?

Comment: To some degree this is apples and oranges. Can you be more specific? What sort of data needs to be transferred? Does the data need to be encrypted?

Comment: Simple form post text and html data, encrypted would be better.

Comment: If data integrity and encryption are high priorities for this, I would definitely recommend against using email; it has the potential to be less reliable and is more difficult to encrypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a whole, Email is much less secured then using a rest API.

Sure you can attach ssl to your mail server / web site that will encrypt your email. However, Emails can be lost as that transfer protocol is less reliable.

With an rest API you define a set rules how the data will be transferred. With an API you don't need to create an account to transfer data though. You can attach SSL to Rest API which will encrypt the data while it is being transferred.

For simple data captured though forms etc. I would personally use an API rather then Email.

However, if you are thinking about a simple contact form on a website a email would probably be more suited, I would still not use it though. It all depends on how complex the solution is that you are trying to develop.

Comment: +1 - Just one comment on the contact form: I would still recommend against email for data delivery, because if you can build the form, you can control its data transfer logic; you effectively would use the same logic as the API would (without the need for an actual API).

Comment: The one thing I can think of for Email is that it acts like a queue and cannot be directly flooded like an api. The mailbox will accept only so many emails and then reject the rest if there are too many all at once. Whereas, you could easily DOS an API. Any thoughts? I guess you could put limits on REST APIs and return 500s which would be the same as rejected emails.

Comment: Yes I personally won't use email.

Comment: There are work a rounds for this using a Queueing Service on top of your API. This acts as the Queue system that you get in email. Also for DDos attacks there are also work a rounds and checks you can put in place to prevent the damage it may cause.

Comment: @pavbhaji - `it acts like a queue and cannot be directly flooded` - to be fair, a mailserver can still be DoS'd, and keep in mind that you may not have access to one or more of the mailservers between your clients and the end server, which can introduce unreliability. Email shouldn't be considered anything more than a glorified system of virtual postcards.